# No rule to make target based on parameter use

Tags: makefile

I am using a makefile to control the compilation of my project. At the start of my Makefile, I have:

```
ifdef PIXEL
    CFLAGS += -DBY_PIXEL
else
 ifdef LINE
    CFLAGS += -DBY_LINE
 else
  ifdef BLOCK
    CFLAGS += -DBY_BLOCK
  else
    CFLAGS += -DBY_PIXEL     (HERE)
  endif
 endif
endif
```

I have the error "No rule to make target XXX" where XXX is PIXEL, LINE or BLOCK. However when I don't write any parameter, it finds the target in the last else (where I put (HERE).

I dont fully understand why but I don't often write Makefile. Do you guys have an idea about it?

Comment: How are you invoking Make?

Comment: "make all PIXEL" for example

Comment: Well that's your problem.  That tells `make` to build two targets; `all` and `PIXEL`.

Comment: your question made me try "make all LINE=1" and it worked fine >< Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a variable for `make`, *set it to a value* after the `make` command. For example, `make PIXEL=foo build`